# Using smaller parent contract consumes less gas?

Tags: solidity, gas

### Here's my Test Code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

// StandardToken is from zepplin-solidity.
import "./StandardToken.sol";

contract Callee {

    address public caller_;

    function setCaller() public {
        caller_ = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract DirectCaller is Callee, StandardToken {

}

contract IndirectCaller {

    function call() public {
        // "0xb87..cfa" is the address of DirectCaller contract
        Callee(0xb87213121fb89cbd8b877cb1bb3ff84dd2869cfa).setCaller();
    } 
}
```

`DirectCaller` inherits two parent contracts, Calle and StandardToken. Since `StandardToken` of zepplin-solidity is pretty big, `DirectCaller`'s compiled bytecodes are also big.

`IndirectCaller` calls `Callee.setCaller()` function using DirectCaller contract with its parent Contract. In my Remix, `DirectCaller.setCaller()` consumes 20394 gas and `IndirectCaller.call()` only consumes 7056 gas.

Is the reason that `IndirectCaller.call()` loads less byte codes that is related with its Parent(in this case, Callee) Contract?

Then, why don't all of us use small sized abstract interface for saving gas consumption?

Comment: Your question mentions abstract interfaces, but I don't see any in your code. I'm also not sure what the significance of the address is. Does that point to an instance of one of the contracts in the code you've shared?

Comment: Without `StandardToken`, if I use an instance of `DirectCaller` and an instance of `IndirectCaller` where `call` uses the address of `DirectCaller`, I find `IndirectCaller.call` takes just a little more gas than `DirectCaller.setCaller`. (29778 vs. 26666) One thing to be careful of: the first call to `setCaller` (however you make it) will cost more because it's setting a zero value in storage to non-zero. Subsequent calls will be cheaper because they're updating an already non-zero value. So when testing this out, just ignore the first call that updates `caller_`.

Comment: Thanks smarx, sorry for the unclear part. I've just edited my question. Could you see it again please?

Comment: You haven't addressed my comment, which claims the opposite findings as you and hypothesizes as to why your measurement may be flawed.

Comment: I missed your point. Now I can see `DirectCaller.setCaller()` costs less. It was the issue of first call. Thanks for your kind reply!

Comment: There's another issue is that they are semantically different `IndirectCaller.call` set itself as a caller but `DirectCaller.setCaller` will set `msg.sender` as caller.

Comment: That's right. It was intended to distinguish direct call from indirect call. Thanks for the reply!